# ECSlidingViewController freezes UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uirefreshcontrol, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm using ECSlidingViewController in my app. I have a View Controller with a UITableView in it, which uses a UIRefreshControl to execute a long task. When I pull down to refresh, the refresh control starts animating normally but when I go to the top view controller (my main menu in this case) and then go back to my view controller, the refreshControl freezes completely until the task is completed.

To make it clearer, these are the steps I follow:

1. Pull down my tableView to refresh it.
2. A long task is executed on background, like:

   ```
   - (void)pulledToRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl
   {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
           long long a = 0;
           for (long long i = 0; i < 100000000000; i++) {
               a++;
           }
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               [refreshControl endRefreshing];
           });
       });
   }
   ```
3. While the refresh control is animating, I **slide** (I **don't** call the `resetTopView:animated:` method or any of those ones, I just make a pan gesture) my current view controller to the right to show my Main Menu. When this happens, the refresh control suddenly stops animating (it freezes).
4. I go back to the view controller I was using at first but it remains frozen.
5. The task completes and the refresh control ends the refresh naturally, removing itself from my tableView with a nice animation.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: This may be a bug in `ECSlidingViewController`. See https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/issues/250

Comment: Good to know that you guys are still working in this and are aware of this bug. Thanks!

Comment: I just pushed a fix for this. Give the latest master branch a try and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Sorry Michael! I've give it a second shot and it seems it still doesn't work =/

Comment: For more info, you can check the way I'm testing it. I just change one file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/kz0xw1ogabdp9a8/METransitionsViewController.m

Comment: I see, you may need to switch to another transition that is not percent driven (for example MEDynamicTransition).The change I made causes the refresh control's animation to stop, but there's no way to make it animate again after that.

Comment: It seemed to work OK before the change. The refresh control's animation would pause while the top view was being swiped. It would continue after the interaction completed. Was that not the behavior you expected?

Comment: Michael, I'm having the same problem... Any updates on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution for this.... Changing the "detectPanGestureRecognizer" method to below, seems to be working for me...

```
- (void)detectPanGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    _isInteractive = YES;
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.defaultInteractiveTransition updateTopViewHorizontalCenterWithRecognizer:recognizer];
});
_isInteractive = NO;
```

}